# Struggle to understand why thread only run for a while then stop

Tags: c

So I implemented an iteration in function that was called by pthread_create, then some threads didn't run, some run for a while. Here my code

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 5

int test[NUM_THREADS] ;  
void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
  printf("id : %d\n",(int)threadid) ; 
   for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
     test[(int)threadid]++ ; 
   }
   printf("NUM OF LOOPS FOR THIS THREAD IS WAS EXECUTED: ,%d",test[(int)threadid]);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc;
  long t;
  int total  = 0 ; 
  for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++){
    printf("Main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
    if (rc){
      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0 ; i <NUM_THREADS ;i++) total +=test[i] ; 
  printf("Total loop was executed %d\n",total);
}
```

Here is output :

```
Main: creating thread 0
Main: creating thread 1
Main: creating thread 2
Main: creating thread 3
id : 0
id : 3
Main: creating thread 4
id : 1
Total loop was executed 14160
```

I run again and got this output :

```
Main: creating thread 0
Main: creating thread 1
Main: creating thread 2
Main: creating thread 3
id : 0
id : 1
Main: creating thread 4
id : 2
Total loop was executed 33124
```

I think I misused something, Sorry if I asked dumb question. C is hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In main(), you should wait for all threads to finish their job.  If you don't, they will all exit prematurely when the main thread exits.  Or you will collect erroneous information.

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc;
  long t;
  int total  = 0 ; 
  for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
  {
     printf("Main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
     rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
     if (rc)
     {
       printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
       exit(-1);  // <-- this closes all threads..
     }
  }

  // ADD THIS
  //
  // wait for all threads to finish what they have to do.
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
     pthread_join (threads[t], NULL);

  for (int i = 0 ; i <NUM_THREADS ;i++) 
    total +=test[i] ; 

  printf("Total loop was executed %d\n",total);
}
```

Comment: It did run all threads but all code behind thread_create weren't executed. I don't understand why